# Office tools to develop sharepoint apps using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, office-365-developer, apps-development, office-365-develop-tool

- One of my client is still using SP 2010 and want to have demo on
  SharePoint 2013 apps ,His development environment is still holding VS
  2010
- Can any one help me in office tools if exists and get installed apps components to develop sharepoint apps for online

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio by searching for "office" in the Web Platform Installer.

[image: Web Platform Installer]

I should note that SharePoint 2010 does not support Apps (Add-Ins)